# When using a variable to call an object from a JSON file, it doesn't call it at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Using JS in conjunction with a JSON file to turn a room ID into the room information.

```
function rooms(roomID) {
    const roomsDB = require("./rooms.json")
    let roomsID = "r".concat("", roomID).toString()
    console.log(roomsDB.roomsID)
}

rooms(46)
```

This is the function I'm using to turn the ID into the info, and the rooms.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "r46":"house"
}
```

Ideally, this would log `house` into the console, but I only get undefined.
Why isn't the JSON object being called properly?

Comment: `roomsDB[roomsID]` - that's how you access object properties programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically access an object property by name in a string variable you need to use brackets:

```
roomsDB[roomsID]
```

The dot (`roomsDB.roomsID`) is just like `roomsDB["roomsID"]`, it doesn't substitute the variable.